# Save firebase notification in text

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Through this code I can display the notification in a text, but I want to save the text until another notification arrives to replace it even if the application is closed

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    setTitle(title);
    TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc1);
    desc.setText(message);
}
```

Comment: use Tinydb or sharedpreference for save text 
https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

Answer (score 0):

**Through TinyDB:**

```
//create an object of tinydb

    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);

    //Put data in tinyDb

    tinydb.putString("text", message);

    //get data from tinydb

    tinydb.getString("text");

    //here is your condition for notification if notification arrives then update tiny db

    //Put data in tinyDb

    tinydb.putString("text", message);
```

**Through SharedPref:**

```
//Save value

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
     editor.putString("text", message);
     editor.apply();
//get value

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
      String name = prefs.getString("text", "Default");//"No name defined" is the default value.

    }
```

Comment: how I do it by sharedpreference